# Mysql 5.6: how to limit the number of update or delete operation

Tags: mysql

**I want this...**

When the update or delete operation affects the number of rows greater than 1000,  is prohibited.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Hint:  `LIMIT XXX`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It sounds like OP wants to block the entire query.

Comment: @Gordon - OP want prohibition not limit.

Comment: Create a procedure. Use the same where clause in select query and get the count(*). If it is greater that your threshold, abort, else proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no functionality builtin to MySQL that achieves this prohibition,  automatically cancelling a DML statement (INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement) that affects more than N rows.

And there's not really a way to implement this kind of restriction for any and all possible INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statements that could be executed.

---

There are a couple of approaches we could take to implement this kind of restriction, but all of those approaches will require some additional SQL statements and logic.

One possibility is to run a separate "precheck" query, using the same criteria as the UPDATE or DELETE statement to be issued, and gather counts of rows that would be affected. And then check the returned count(s) to determine whether an UPDATE or DELETE should be issued. This approach doesn't provide any restriction or prohibition on a DML statement itself. These are extra steps that need to be performed *apart* from the actual DML statement.

---

Another possibility, to effect this type of restriction would be to implement FOR EACH ROW TRIGGERs on specific tables that track the number of times the trigger is fired.

The trigger would need to increment a counter in a user-defined variable (e.g. `@rowlimit`, and need compare the cumulative counter to a specified limit (coded into the trigger), and then `SIGNAL` (or otherwise throw an error) when the specified limit is reached or exceeded. Throwing an error would cause the operation to be cancelled.

This approach would also require a preliminary statement to reset the user-defined variable to zero, before each INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement is issued, e.g. `SET @rowlimit = 0`.

It's important to note that triggers are not fired for rows affected through FOREIGN KEY constraint actions. To also include counts of those rows, the BEFORE UPDATE/BEFORE DELETE trigger on the parent table would need to perform a query to find the number of rows that would be affected in the child tables.

To implement this kind of restriction across the board, for a lot of tables, would require a lot of triggers to be defined.

---

If we don't *prohibit* the DML statement from affecting any rows, but instead   allow a DML statement to affect up to a certain number of rows, and just stop when that limit is reached, allowing the statement to complete successfully, we can add a LIMIT clause on the DML statement. This approach obviously requires modifying the DML statement, and doesn't prohibit the entire operation. It only specifies a "maximum" number of rows, and when that "maximum" number is reached, the statement stops processing further rows, leaving the "maximum" number of rows affected, and completes successfully.

---

The only way to prohibit DML statements that will affect more than N rows would be to entirely prohibit all DML statements that might affect more than 0 rows (y revoking UPDATE, DELETE and INSERT privileges.

As an alternative, we could create MySQL stored programs (i.e. PROCEDURES) that do perform well defined "update and delete operations". Those procedures can defined (`DEFINER`) to run under the privileges of a user that *does* have privilege to execute DML statements against tables. And other users could be  granted `EXECUTE` privilege on those procedures, so that those users can perform well defined "update and delete" operations.

---

None of these approaches fully satisfies the specification... to prohibit DML operations that affect more than a specified limit of rows.